# HP Web Tours Server crash issue

Tags: loadrunner

I am unable to launch HP Web Tours Server for Loadrunner Community Edition Please advice command prompt window disappear right after the launch I am using windows 7 64 bit 1 day before it was working perfect

Comment: http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/Tutorial/WebTours.htm Did you do step 4 in prerequisites?

Comment: Go to the location where HP WebTours is installed. [C:\XXXXX\HP\LoadRunner\WebTours]  Open [CommandPrompt] cmd and run StartServer.bat file in cmd. You will see the error. Please paste that for further help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and couldn't start the Web tours server after upgrading my Java version. The following solution worked for me.

Opened `httpd.conf` file in the below directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\LoadRunner\WebTours\conf
```

Changed Listen port from 1080 to 1090 and was able to start web tours application.

Default Value:

```
Listen 1080
```

Modified value

```
Listen 1090
```

Now to access web tours application, use URL `http://127.0.0.1:1090/WebTours/index.htm`

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack overflow, check out the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer it provides some nice tips to improve your answer and thus reputation ;)